# BigQuery streaming insert using template tables data availability issue

Tags: streaming, google-bigquery

We have been using BigQuery for over a year now with no issues. We load data as batch jobs every few hours and it usually is instantly available.

We just started experimenting with streaming inserts using template tables. With our first test, we saw no errors and the data showed up instantly. The test created approximately 120 tables. A simple select count (using the web ui) on the tables came up with the right total number of ~8000 rows. After a couple of hours of more streaming, the total dropped to ~1400 rows.

Unsure about what happened, we dropped the dataset, recreated the template table and re-ran the streaming. This time around, the tables showed up right away but the data did not. On our third attempt the tables themselves did not show up for more than a couple of hours. We are on the fourth attempt and this time we only streamed data belonging to one table. The table showed up right away, but it has been over an hour and the data does not show up.

The streaming service uses the latest Java library, inserts only one record at a time and logs the response. The response, without an exception is always {"kind":"bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse"} and no errors.

Any help trying to understand what is happening would be great. Thanks.

Comment: If you can give us your project/template table/suffixes, we can take a look. That said, there may be caching interactions coming into play... If you delete tables, you may need to wait a few minutes for our caches to clear before you try to stream again. Otherwise we'll have bound your inserts to your deleted table... and then drop those rows (because we think the table they're associated with is gone).

Comment: Sean, Thank you for your quick response. We did wait for around 10 minutes after deleting tables, before we started streaming again. We will try this test once again by deleting the tables, waiting for an hour (just to make sure) and try streaming. If we still see the issue, we will get back to you with the project and other details. Once again, Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the updates that were pushed yesterday and had some serious issues, thus there is a incident on BQ: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/18013

Comment: @Pentium10 Thank you for the pointer. I don't get any errors when streaming data, so this is probably something else

Comment: @SeanChen We gave it a few hours of cooling after we deleted the tables. Then we restarted the streaming. Our logs show that we streamed 11094 rows, while we only see 8207 rows in BigQuery.

Comment: The project is 'fanplayr-tracking-data', template table is 'orders_' and the dataset name is 'stream'. Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: @RajivSunkara - We're looking into it. If you want to email me your contact information at seanchen@google, we'll follow up with our investigation.

Comment: I'm having the same type of problem. I'm testing out an automated job load, so lots of "bq rm -f -t dataset.table", then stream a load with a template suffix of a date, then try to read from table to do a 'bq query --destination_table=destination_table --append_table "select... from template_2016_02_17" '. I thought I had coding issues but there were no errors. How long should I wait? How do I know when the suffixed table is ready to reuse again? thx @SeanChen

Comment: I see your table was created, and data was added. However, it looks like you've hit an edge condition that will basically render "immediate availability via template inserts" disabled for your template table until one of the following occurs: 1) Template table inserts on the destination are idle for a while (O(hours)) -- if you start streaming again, immediate availability will start working OR 2) You delete and recreate your base table (waiting a few minutes for our caches to clear). We'll look into remedying this issue, but we do recommend extra care when modify generated tables directly.

Comment: I should have said "... disabled for your generated table". Other generated table (different suffixes) should work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like we've identified the issue. It appears there's a race in the template-tables path *only* that causes our system to think the first chunk of data was deleted by user action (table truncation -- which it obviously wasn't), and is dropped. We've identified the fix and will attempt to push out a fix shortly.

Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: how big is a "chunk of data"?

Comment: @FooL the size varies. It depends on how fast you are inserting streaming data. also BTW the race condition should be fixed now.

Comment: Second note: The race only exists for generated template tables that were delete, and then recreated by the streaming system.

Comment: I just tried & I'm still getting an error: 'exchange-reporting-dw:bqjob_r3888baca5e773dca_00000152fcea678f_1': Not found:
Table
exchange-reporting-dw:reporting_dw.exchange_campaign_staging_tmpl_2016_02_19

Comment: Should I `sleep` for a bit after the delete before streaming?

Comment: @FooL It looks like your query started around the time of your table deletion. In this scenario, the component that handles template table only sees a cached version of the metadata so it didn't realize the table deletion until 2/19 20:31 PST (roughly 10min after the table deletion). that's why the generated table didn't get re-created immediately after the deletion.

Comment: @FooL In this situation (delete, and wait for bq to auto-create the table again), sleep can help. But it still suffers from losing the 'immediate query availability' as Sean mentioned in the comment above. We are working on a remedy. The 2 workaround mentioned by Sean should work for you in this case. In general it's not recommended to manipulate (delete, re-create, update) the generated table until you are done streaming to the table.